# Sequelize showing error: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to update a record in mysql database using sequelize but it is not working.

I am getting this error

Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Model

```
module.exports = sequelize.define("branches", {
address: Sequelize.TEXT(),
company: Sequelize.STRING(),
 codeConfig: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    get: function () {
        return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('codeConfig'));
    },
    set: function (val) {
        return this.setDataValue('codeConfig', JSON.stringify(val));
    }
},

});
```

Update function

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {

const { address, company} = req.body;

 try {

    const branches = await Branches.findOne({ where: { code: req.params.id } });
    if (!branches) return res.json({ msg: "Branch Not Found" });

    Branches.update({ "address": "No. 10 distreet street" }, {
        where: {
            code: "WHJ5uBdriI"
        }
    }).then(function (newBranch) {
        return res.json({ msg: "Updated" });
    });


} catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
}

});
```

Error output

[image]

Comment: Could you try `console.log(this.getDataValue('codeConfig'))` in get function before the `JSON.parse`?  My guess is that this raw value in DB is not in valid JSON.

Comment: @Emma I have tried it but it did not show any value

Comment: I see. That means the `this.getDataValue('codeConfig')` is undefined somehow.  try `console.log(this.toJSON())`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `autoJsonMap: false,` to your sequelize's `dialectOptions`

Example:

```
let sequelize = new Sequelize(DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD, {
    // some other options
    dialectOptions: {
        autoJsonMap: false,
    }
});
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12583

Answer (score 0):

i have noticed that before sequelize make a field update, it fetches through all fields, and then execute a getter function if exist, so for that i added an if check inside a getter, here is the code now the model.update working:

```
get: function () {
   if(this.getDataValue('codeConfig') !== undefined){ 
    /// appentely sequelize tried to parse the value of 'codeConfig' but its undefined since you are updating only address field.
    return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('codeConfig'));
  }
},
```